# Mouse hover action to browser window close button

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java, javascript

I have a test scenario where the web application checks for the user's leave intent i.e., mouse hovering from the page to the browser close and then a frame gets triggered. Is there any way to do it?

Edit: So the dev implementation is that when the user is moving to the top of the document frame gets triggered and it is not browser close but moving to corner of the document.

Answer (score 0):

The browser close button cannot be hovered with WebDriver. You could try to close the current window with `driver.close()` and see if the close is blocked and the message is shown.

- Move mouse top top of page: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12974488/selenium-webdriver-move-mouse-to-point
- You could try to automate non browser page actions with [SikuliX](http://sikulix.com/quickstart/) or [AutoIt](https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-webdriver/autoit-selenium-webdriver/). Still I would try to not take this path, as it makes tests harder to setup, harder run (also on test servers), more complex to understand.

I would sit with the developers and see how you can make this testable as simple as possible. For example by implementing [window.onbeforeunload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2229942/how-to-block-users-from-closing-a-window-in-javascript) to prevent the window from closing without confirmation, which is testable by using `driver.close()`.

Comment: I do not think he wants to close the browser, what he is asking for is a way to check if user wants to close the browser/tab by pressing the "X" button and if so, display some pop up.

Comment: @Moro Agreed, I answered that with AutoIt and SikuliX, but I think the implementation of detecting that "wants" of a user is hard and even harder to test. So let the user click on the close button and just cancel the close in the onbeforeunload, which is default browser behaviour and thus cross-platform. I dont think we should blindly follow requirements, but suggest better implementations that are testable and future proof.

Comment: @niels I just edited and added some more context.

Comment: @AdithyaRam Added a link to move the mouse to a position. That is really weird behaviour you are describing. Certainly does not fit my mental model of how websites should behave.

Comment: @niels I have used the following code `Actions actions = new Actions(driver);
        actions.moveToElement(element).click()
                .moveByOffset(10,25).click()
                .keyUp(Keys.CONTROL).build().perform();` where element is top most element in the page . But it didnot work even though i changed the offset values

Comment: @AdithyaRam Why click on elements or use keyUp? Probably you first have to move the mouse to an element below the trigger area and then move it into the trigger area. Something like: `new Actions(driver).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("belowarea"))).build().perform(); new Actions(driver).moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("intriggerarea"))).build().perform();`

Comment: @Neils tried it but no luck. I moved from inside page to html body with offset(0,0)

Answer (score 0):

I did it using Sikuli:

```
//imports
import org.sikuli.script.FindFailed;
import org.sikuli.script.Pattern;
import org.sikuli.script.Screen;

//Code Snippets
Screen s = new Screen();
Pattern browserCloseButton = new Pattern(filepath + "CloseButton.PNG");

WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get(<url>);

s.hover(browserCloseButton);
```

For more reference read up:
https://www.guru99.com/sikuli-tutorial.html
http://doc.sikuli.org/region.html

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so apparently what you need to do is capture some `WebElement` on top of the page and then move mouse by offset using `Actions` class. Using `Java` it would be something like this:

```
    WebElement topElement = driver.findElement(By.SOME_SELECTOR);
    Actions action=new Actions(driver);
    action.moveToElement(topElement).moveByOffset(0, -100).perform();
```

It does not have to be "-100" just enough to move outside the viewport and trigger the desired frame.